# Extending a Field Monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In theorem A3.5 of Ash's book *Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year* ([page 20 in this pdf](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter3.pdf)), the author set out to prove the following.

> Let $\sigma:  F \rightarrow L$ be a field monomorphism where $L$ is algebraically closed.  If $E/F$ is algebraic, then $\sigma$ extends to a monomorphism $\tau:  E \rightarrow L$.

Here is the full statement and proof:

> [image]

The proof is essentially an application of Zorn's lemma.  However, the author never explicitly explained why it is necessary for $L$ to be algebraically closed.

Here is a counter-example with the condition removed:  Stack $E/L/F$ into a chain of extensions where $E$ is algebraically closed and a proper extension of $L$.  As a result, we cannot have any monomorphism from $E$ into $L$.

Now, how do I weave this observation into the proof?

Comment: Well, I would look into (A3.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a  look at A3.4:

> [image]

The fact that $L$ is algebraically closed implies that the number of distinct roots of the polynomial $f\in F[x]$ in an algebraic closure of $F$ is equal to the number of distinct roots of $\sigma f\in L[x]$ in $L$.

Comment: I did not entirely understood A3.4 and skipped it.  On second look, it seems that we want $L$ to be algebraically closed so that the image of the extension is in $L$.  If $\beta_1, \beta_2 \ldots \beta_m$ are the distinct roots of $\sigma f$, then $F(\alpha) \cong (\sigma F)(\beta_i)$ where $i \in \{ \, 1, 2 \ldots m \, \}$.  This gives us the $m$ extensions associated with $\alpha \in E$.  If $L$ is not algebraically closed, then some of the extensions may not land on $L$.  I still need to stew over the details, but the big picture looks right, TY ....